# I Want To Install Ubuntu 13.04 On Windows 8 With Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

Laptop: HP Probook 4520s
Windows: Windows 8 x64

This is what I want

I want to install Ubuntu 13.04

When my computer starts, I want it to give me option to choose to load Windows 8 or Ubuntu

- As Windows 8 boot loader option (that blue screen, not the Ubuntu screen asking for it)
- If i dont choose within 15 seconds, windows 8 loads default as automatically
- Also I want to be able to change the defaults

Can anyone help me and guide me step by step what should I do to install Ubuntu over windows 8 to get what I want

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
There are already similar questions, but in this case, Windows is not UEFI, I have installed windows 8 myself, built in windows was Windows 7 in my laptop
And I can not understand or find the easy steps to do the above anywhere

Comment: Hmm. Are you *sure* you don't have UEFI?

Comment: Is this what you're after?: http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

> As Windows 8 boot loader option (that blue screen, not the Ubuntu screen asking for it)

- [This guide](http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm) might help you get it done. Basically:

  - Create 3 partitions
  - Install Windows 8
  - Install Ubuntu
  - Swap

> If i dont choose within 15 seconds, windows 8 loads default as automatically

- For this you need [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

> Also I want to be able to change the defaults

- I'm not sure what you mean here, but I'm guessing which OS comes first. You can also edit this with EasyBCD. I believe it's either in the Advanced Settings or Edit Boot Menu categories.

Though honestly if you want to avoid troubles getting an external drive to install either OS will save you from further troubles in setting up boot options and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu onto a secondary (slave) hard drive. The Ubuntu installation configures everything automatically so that you can:

a) have a dual boot

b) Windows is the default boot option (if you don't select within 15 seconds)

I'm not sure about changing the defaults, but this shouldn't be a problem.

This seems far easier and hassle-free than creating 3 partitions.

Good luck.